# prove that $ \ U \ $ is constant on the gradient trajectory $ \ r(t) \ $ of $ \ V \ $

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider two real valued differentiable functions $ U,V \ $ satisfying Cauchy -Riemann equations $$ U_x=V_y, \ U_y=-V_x \ $$ 
Then prove that $ \ U \ $ is constant on the gradient trajectory $ \ r(t) \ $ of $ \ V \ $.

Answer:

Now,

$ U_x=V_y \Rightarrow U_{xx}=V_{yx} , \\ U_y=-V_x \Rightarrow U_{yy}=-V_{xy} $

Adding both  , we get

$ U_{xx}+U_{yy}=V_{yx}-V_{xy}=0 \ $

Because $ \ V_{xy}=V_{yx} \ $, as V is diffentiable, its partial derivatives are constant.

$ \therefore \ \Delta U=0 $

How to conclude the proof?

I need help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One doesn't directly need $\nabla^2U = \nabla^2V = 0$ here; what works is to observe that Cauchy-Riemann implies $\nabla U \cdot \nabla V = 0$, to wit:

$\dot r = (V_x, V_y) = \nabla V(r(t)); \tag 1$

$\dot U(r(t)) = \nabla U(r(t)) \cdot \dot r$$= \nabla U(r(t)) \cdot \nabla V(r(t)) = U_x(r(t)) V_x(r(t)) + U_y(r(t)) V_y(r(t)); \tag 2$

from Cauchy-Riemann,

$U_x(r(t)) = V_y(r(t)), \; U_y(r(t)) = -V_x(r(t)); \tag 3$

thus (2) becomes

$\dot U(r(t)) = U_x(r(t)) V_x(r(t)) + U_y(r(t)) V_y(r(t))$
$= V_y(r(t)) (- U_y(r(t)) + U_y(r(t)) V_y(r(t)) = 0. \tag 4$